# How did Andy's Bible get into the warden's locker?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-shawshank-redemption

I watched *The Shawshank Redemption* countless times. This question occurred to me tonight for the very first time.

When the Warden opened the safe at the end of the movie, Andy's Bible was there. Norton then dropped it on the floor and went to his desk.

How did the Bible get in the safe?
The night before, Andy had to wait for Norton to open the safe so he could put the other ledger in.

[image]

Comment: I think Andy replaced Warden's original documents and other stuff with some of his documents and Bible may be one among them... When warden opens his safe to Andy to put all the ledgers and stuff, that's when Andy put fake documents/ledgers and kept the original legal documents for him. That's how he was able to get all the money the very next day

Answer (score 12):

After Andy's escape, it is narrated that how he got escaped, visited the bank and did other stuff. That's when we see that when the warden opens the locker, Andy puts the ledger under his coat and the bible in the locker. He swapped the ledger and other docs with the Bible which is shown in your screenshot.

[image]

[image]

Since the Warden was busy opening the locker, he couldn't see Andy doing this. Therefore he wouldn't have known. Moreover, the color of cover of the ledger book and the Bible is almost same, so the warden couldn't notice it too.

[image]